# What statistical analysis method should I use for two independent variables with interval data and a dependent variable with continuous data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, correlation, anova

I'm doing a study on the potential of date leaf ash and date fruit seeds as replacement materials for cement and sand, respectively. For date leaf ash (DLA), there is 0% replacement and 5% replacement, and for date fruit seeds (DFS) there is 0%, 5%, and 10% replacement, so all of my treatment groups are as follows:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 0DLA, 0DFS | 5DLA, 0DFS |
| 0DLA, 5DFS | 5DLA, 5DFS |
| 0DLA, 10DFS | 5DLA, 10DFS |

My dependent variable is the compressive strength of the concrete samples and the ideal outcome is for the compressive strengths of treatments with date leaf ash and/or date fruit seeds to be equal or higher than that of ordinary concrete.

To determine the statistical effect of these variables, I tried using Two-Way ANOVA, but it doesn't take into account the fact that the independent variables are not categorical data, but rather interval. I also do not know whether Pearson's r correlation is valid for this case because the percentages aren't continuous and the interaction between the two independent variables are not taken into account.

What other statistical analysis methods could work? Or were any of the ones I mentioned already sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

It is equally valid to frame this general-linear-model (GLM) analysis as a) a two-way ANOVA using the 2 levels of one independent variable and the 3 levels of another and b) a linear regression using the interval-level values of each independent variable.  The latter choice seems to fit your preference, as it will shed the most light on the problem as you conceptualize it.  Either way, you will want to build in an interaction term.  Pearson's r will be a bivariate indicator only; it will not simultaneously take into account both independent variables' main effects, let alone assess them for an interaction.